# What is the most elegant way of encapsulating a multi-step calculation?

Tags: c#, encapsulation, coroutine, yield-return

As a more specific example - I have a game loop and I want to have a method handle an animation.

This animation is, for the sake of this example, a call to a movement function.

Is there a way I can call this function and have it do... something when the animation is complete automatically?

The more basic implementation would be to have it return a value when completed, and have the caller continually check for this, but I seem to remember there are more elegant tricks.

I know nothing about co-routines or the yield keyword. could they be relevant here?

Comment: You can use await to simulate coroutines. await does not start a new thread, nor does it block.

Comment: can you give an actual code example? I can think of a composite pattern, but that might not be applicable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer largely is: **it depends**

If the code is, as you say, a simple method call (that you have no control over), and that method call is being run in a loop (as opposed to being long-running), you are pretty much stuck with the "check return value" method.

If it only a *function*, but is long-running, you can pass it a callback. Your function signature becomes:

```
public void foo MyFunc(Action callback)
{
   ...
   callback();
}
```

And you would call it with an `Action` delegate (of course any other delegate would be fine as long as you update the function signature). The callback would be called by `foo` when the operation was completed. This is usually done in a threading environment, since you could just wait for the call to return on a single thread.

In a threaded environment, you could also just wait for the thread to `Join` if the thread termination would coincide with your "completion" condition.

In the best case, this functionality is encapsulated into a class that manages the state between the looped method calls. In this case, you can simply raise an event that the using class registers for when the operation completes.

The last is the most verbose option, but does allow for looped calls (as in a game loop) or threading and can call multiple functions on completion. If it makes sense in your use case, I would go with this option.

Comment: wouldn't the example given still tie up the execution of the code though? If foo had a big loop in it for example. I basically just want to kick something off that will handle itself and then callback when done. The callback part I get, but how can I just set something in motion but not have it retain control until it's done?

Comment: @SirYakalot Start it on its own thread (hence the comment about it normally being done in a threaded environment). That will do *exactly* what you just described. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SirYakalot I noticed you un-accepted my answer. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide. Starting your function in its own thread (and passing the callback) should get you where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to do something when it finishes, try using callbacks: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

It would look something like:

```
public void Animate(Function foo)
{
    // Animate
    foo();
}
```

Comment: You should probably use valid C# as well :). I agree that its not a link-only answer though.